# Setting the samesite-Attribute for CherryPy's sessions

Tags: python, cookies, cherrypy

I am programming a software using CherryPy. I am using the normal sessions, using 'cherrypy.session'.
Now I noticed Firefox complaining I am using the "wrong" samesite-Attribute and that it possibly will not be available in the future anymore.

Is there a way to set the samesite-Attribute of the session-cookies for CherryPy to another value?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of tricky as already discussed several times (e.g., look [here](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1767))
This means that apparently there is no solution for python < 3.8.
However, you can still use monkeypatch.
So do the following to solve the problem:

1. Open ../python3.x/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py
2. Add the following codes at the beginning of the file

   ```
    from http import cookies
    cookies.Morsel._reserved.setdefault('samesite', 'SameSite')
   ```
3. close and save it
4. open ../python3.x/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py
5. change the following function definition

   ```
   def init(storage_type=None, path=None, path_header=None, name='session_id',
    timeout=60, domain=None, secure=False, clean_freq=5,
    persistent=True, httponly=False, debug=False,
    # Py27 compat
    # *, storage_class=RamSession,
    **kwargs):
   ```

to

```
    def init(storage_type=None, path=None, path_header=None,
      name='session_id',
      timeout=60, domain=None, secure=False, clean_freq=5,
      persistent=True, httponly=False,samesite='lax' debug=False,
      # Py27 compat
      # *, storage_class=RamSession,
      **kwargs):
```

6. Change the following:

   ```
     set_response_cookie(path=path, path_header=path_header, name=name,
                     timeout=cookie_timeout, domain=domain, secure=secure,
                     httponly=httponly)
   ```

to:

```
     set_response_cookie(path=path, path_header=path_header, name=name,
                     timeout=cookie_timeout, domain=domain, secure=secure,
                     httponly=httponly,samesite=samesite)
```

7. change the following:

   ```
   def set_response_cookie(path=None, path_header=None, name='session_id',
       timeout=60, domain=None, secure=False, httponly=False):
   ```

to:

```
def set_response_cookie(path=None, path_header=None, name='session_id',
       timeout=60, domain=None, secure=False, httponly=False,samesite='lax'):
```

8. add this code to the end of the set_response_cookie() method:

   ```
    if samesite in ['lax', 'strict', None]:
        cookie[name]['samesite'] = str(samesite)
   ```
9. save the file and close it.

Now in your code (driver) you can use the "samesite" attribute like this:

```
'tools.sessions.samesite': 'strict'
```

or

```
'tools.sessions.samesite': 'lax' # This is the default value
```

good luck!

Comment: What if I have python 3.8, should I do the same?